# Prove $\lim_{t\to 0+} \frac{f(x_{i+1}-t)-f(x_{i+1}-)}{t}=-g'_i(x_{i+1})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ function is called piecewise differentiable if there exists a partition $P  :x_0=a<x_1<\ldots<x_m=b$ and $g_i:[x_i,x_{i+1}]\to \mathbb R$, $0\leq i \leq m-1$, differentiable functions s.t. $f(x)=g_i(x),x\in(x_i,x_{i+1})$.

My book without proof mentions that $$\lim_{t\to 0+} \frac{f(x_{i+1}-t)-f(x_{i+1}-)}{t}=-g'_i(x_{i+1}).$$ Can you explain how this follows?

Comment: @coudy left limit at that point

Comment: How would you define $g'_i(x_{i+1})$? It looks almost like a direct substitution for values of $g$ in that definition.

Comment: @DavidK $lim_{t\to 0}\frac{g(x_{i+1}+t)-g(x_{i+1})}{t}$

Comment: $f(x_{i+1}-t)-f(x_{i+1}^-) =g_i(x_{i+1}-t)-g_i(x_{i+1}).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $g_i$ is a function defined only on the closed interval
$[x_i,x_{i+1}],$
but the formula in the question uses the expression $g_i'(x_{i+1}).$

According to many elementary textbooks, $g_i'(x_{i+1})$ is not defined because
$g_i$ does not exist on a punctured neighborhood of $\mathbb R$
surrounding $x_{i+1}.$
In order even to use $g_i'(x_{i+1})$ in a formula,
you need a definition of the derivative that allows $g_i'(x_{i+1})$ to exist.
You get this by using a definition that allows you to ignore the fact that
$g_i(t)$ is not defined for any $t > x_{i+1}.$
There is more than one way to do this, but what it comes down to in the end is you will (in effect, if not explicitly) take some kind of left-side limit instead of the ordinary two-sided limit of the expression
$ \dfrac{g(x_{i+1}+t)-g(x_{i+1})}{t}. $

To skip a lot of extra mechanics of domains and limit points and so forth,
let's just use an explicit left-side limit as follows:
$$
g_i'(x_{i+1}) = \lim_{t\to 0^-} \frac{g(x_{i+1}+t)-g(x_{i+1})}{t}.
$$

But that means all the values of $t$ are negative, which could be confusing.
Let's replace $t$ with $-t$ so that we can use all positive values of $t$:
$$
g_i'(x_{i+1}) = \lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{g(x_{i+1}+(-t))-g(x_{i+1})}{-t}
= -\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{g(x_{i+1}-t)-g(x_{i+1})}{t}. \tag1
$$

Now for $x_i < x_{i+1}-t < x_{i+1},$ a left-side neighborhood of $x_{i+1}$ we observe that $g(x_{i+1}-t) = f(x_{i+1}-t),$ so we can replace
$g(x_{i+1}-t)$ by $f(x_{i+1}-t)$ on the right-hand side of $(1)$.
Also, $f(x_{i+1}^-) = \lim_{x\to x_{i+1}^-} f(x) = g(x_{i+1}),$
so we can replace $g(x_{i+1})$ by $f(x_{i+1}^-).$ And now we have
$$
g_i'(x_{i+1}) = -\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{g(x_{i+1}-t) - f(x_{i+1}^-)}{t}.
$$

Therefore $-g_i'(x_{i+1})$ is equal to the formula shown in the book.